# Server.close() not stoping

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, node-modules

Below is a simple code which I wrote :-

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(function (req,res) {
  res.end("Hello World") 
})

server.listen(5000);



setTimeout(() => {server.close() } ,4000);   // put anytime duration here
```

The behaviour which I expected was that server should stay on for 4 seconds and then closes. But rather what is happening is that server stays on indefinitely and we can do anything, however when we leave server idle for 4 seconds, after that if we reload or do anything  then the timer of 5 seconds starts and after that server closes.
Means from 0 to n seconds I kept on working, then left idle for 4 seconds, on 24th second I reloaded again and then on 29th second the server is closing.

Why is it happening like that.  Basically settimeout will move to call queue after 5 seconds and then it should be moved to call stack by event loop and close  the server as soon as it goes idle.We can put anytime duration in timeout we have to wait leave server idle for that duration for the settimeout to begin and after that 5 seconds it take to close it.
Why is it behaving so ?

I expected that the server shall close after 4 seconds but it is not happening so.

Comment: seems that this is a known issue, apparently, there are workarounds to fix this issue, like installing an external library to accomplish this, you can have more details here: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/2642

Comment: The issue was raised  7 years ago , I think there must have been some upgradation since then. I am a newbie in Node.js so thought that maybe you are aware of some concept or something which can be done.

Comment: other than the library https://github.com/LuKks/graceful-http suggested, I'm afraid I'm not.

Comment: No issue , thank you very much for providing me the link. i at last got the satisfaxtion that nothing is wrong from my side.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that **setTimeout** is non-blocking and does not wait for the server to finish processing any requests before closing. This means that even though **server.close()** is called after 5 seconds, the server continues to process any requests that were already in progress at that time. To ensure that the server closes after 5 seconds, regardless of any active requests, you can use the **server.unref()** method before calling **setTimeout**. This method tells node.js to not keep the event loop running solely for the server, so that it can close as soon as there are no other events to process.

```
server.unref();
setTimeout(() => {server.close() } ,5000);
```

Comment: still behaving in same manner.